# Why are JetBrains YAML tab settings disabled?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I can't edit a YAML file successfully because JetBrains insists on converting tabs to spaces. When I try to fix this setting, it's disabled, why?

[image]

Comment: YAML requires spaces, see http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534 which says, "To maintain portability, tab characters must not be used in indentation..."  Could this be the reason you can't check the box?  How are spaces preventing you from editing a YAML file?

Comment: @EMC Paul is correct. As to way it's there and disabled -- that's just how their interface works.

Comment: yes, I got it backwards. Tabs are correct, spaces are not. My ide settings were using 4 spaces as one tab, which looks the same but isn't correct for yaml.